# Filter values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to filter data based on a row. However, when I filter values based on rows, the result is that the values do not display. How do I solve this issue? Thank you for all your help and time.

```py
fifa = fifa[(fifa['short_name']=='D.Nunez')]
```

[image]

Comment: Your result is an empty table. Check your spelling: Is it e.g. 'D.Nunez' or 'D. Nunez'?

Comment: there could be whitespace characters in the name in the table. It needs to match exactly. refer to guidelines here in posting questions  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in the general category of inexact matches - here are a few very simple methods to help:

```
import pandas as pd
fifa = pd.DataFrame(["D. Nunez"], columns=['short_name'])

print("Contains substring")
print(fifa[(fifa['short_name'].str.contains('Nunez'))])
print("Compare space-less to spaceless")
print(fifa[(fifa['short_name'].str.replace(" ","") == 'D. Nunez'.replace(" ",""))])
print("Compare lowered to lowered")
print(fifa[(fifa['short_name'].str.lower() == 'd. Nunez'.lower())])
```

Each of these matches

```
Contains substring
  short_name
0   D. Nunez
Compare space-less to spaceless
  short_name
0   D. Nunez
Compare lowered to lowered
  short_name
0   D. Nunez
```

You can also chain them, like so:

```
print(fifa[(fifa['short_name'].str.lower().str.replace(" ","") == 'd. Nunez'.lower().replace(" ",""))])
```

Note above that Pandas series requires the str. prefix, while a normal string does not.

To delve further into this topic you would look at using regex, which is powerful and worth the investment.

To go a bit deeper you might look at a technique like Levenshtein Distance which lets you calculate how similar two strings are, and can match even when there are typos.

But perhaps those are topics for another day.